# How to install VMware Tools in Ubuntu

Tags: 23.04, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 as a Guest OS on VMware Workstation. Please let me know how install VMware Tools.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this procedure:

**Check** whether the tools are installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep "open-vm-tools"
```

**Install** them:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Confirm suggested packages.

If your Ubuntu is server (without X11/Wayland), then install cli version:

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools
```

Reboot the Ubuntu and check if VMware workstation see the VM tools are present in the VM details.